# Does accessing subviews of a UIWebView violates Apple 3.3.1 agreement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

I'm developping an iPhone app on which I want to be able to programmatically zoom on a UIWebView, so I have the following piece of code :

```
// Iterate on subviews
for (UIView *scroll in [webView subviews]) {
    // Verify the subview is a UIScrollView
    if([scroll isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    // Cast in UIScroolView and Zoom
    [(UIScrollView*)scroll setZoomScale:2.5f animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, but as it seems that subviews of UIWebView doesn't appear in any Apple API / documentation, can this piece of code be rejected by Apple when I'll want to publish on the App store ?
Putted differently, in what extend **Apple 3.3.1 agreement** applies ?

> APIs and Functionality: 3.3.1 Applications may only use Published APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any unpublished or private APIs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subviews` property is published implicitly via `UIView` base class, and you are using it in the manner prescribed by Apple, e.g. no pointer hacking. So I think it is fine.

Comment: Agree, apple store police didn't complain when I did this.

Comment: Actually, from my experience of submitting apps, I think they don't care much about this rule, unless it is too obvious that you break it.

Comment: I've submitted apps already with this approach to disable scrolling for ads. Shouldn't be a problem.